# PHP - get name of array in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get the name (`John, Mark, ...`) of the array with only knowing the `id`.

`array_search` Doesn't work for me, i have no clue...

```
Array (
    [data] => Array
        (
            [John] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 266
                )

            [Mark] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 412
                )

            [Diana] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 23
                )
)    )
```

Comment: you can traverse your array using `for($array as $key=>$value) {echo  $key."-".$value;}`

Comment: This post shows a horrible lack of effort. There is no question just an outline of some data. `I have no clue` is not a proper problem statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why doesn't array search work for you? are you using a foreach to loop over [data]?

lets assume (since it is not provided) that your whole array is named $array.

```
function getname($id){
   foreach($array['data'] as $row){
       $name = array_search($id,$row);
       return $name;
   }
}
```

when you call this function like this for example.

```
$name = getname(23);
```

$name will be 'Diana';

or am I totally missing the point?

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array iterating on both keys and values and look at the values:

```
function findById(array $array, $id) {
  foreach ($array as $name => $data) {
    if ($data['id'] == $id) {
      return $name;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

echo findById($arr['data'], 412);
```

Answer (score 0):

If array_search doesn't work for multidimensional array
You still can make a function like :

```
function findNamInArray($array, $id) {
    foreach($array as $name => $subArray) {
        if($subArray['id'] == $id) 
          return $name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP 5.5's [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function

```
$myData = array (
    'data' => array (
        'John' => array (
            'id' => 266,
        ),
        'Mark' => array (
            'id' => 412,
        ),
        'Diana' => array (
            'id' => 23,
        ),
    )
);

$id = 412;

$result = array_search(
    $id,
    array_combine(
        array_keys($myData['data']),
        array_column($myData['data'], 'id')
    )
);

var_dump($result);
```

Or even

```
$result = key(
    array_filter(
        $myData['data'],
        function($value) use ($id) {
            return $value['id'] == $id;
        }
    )
);

var_dump($result);
```

which will work with earlier versions of PHP, as long as the id value exists

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to query several times this data structure, you should transform the array in a more suitable form.

You should traverse the array and create a new one of the form

```
$array = Array(
[266] => 'John',
[412] => 'Mark',
[23] => 'Diana',
... 
)
```

Then you just need to query with `$array[id]`

Comment: Unfortunately i get the arrays from an API. So i can't change it

Comment: You can change the data after you receive it from the API ;)
In any case, you'll algorithm would be O(n), assuming that querying arrays is O(constant).